# Deleting a Node from a linked list runs but does not delete anything

Tags: c++, class, templates, pointers, nodes

I am stuck on deleting a node from a linked list. I was able to insert the nodes and display all of them, but I cannot delete one of them. I am suppose to delete the `acct` that matches the same number that `temp` has. This means that `acct2` will be deleted since it matches the number for `temp`, 5678. Everything runs and there is no error, but when I display the list, the `acct2` is still there and nothing gets deleted. I don't know know why it doesn't get deleted. Could it be that the `deleteNode` function is not correct?

This is in main.

```
LinkedList<CheckAcct> list;

vector<string> v = { "Cpt America", "Peter Parker" };
CheckAcct acct1(v, 1234); 
list.insertNode(acct1);

v.clear();
v.push_back("Jon Snow"); 
CheckAcct acct2(v, 5678);  
list.insertNode(acct2);

list.displaylist();

v.clear();
CheckAcct temp(v, 5678); 
list.deleteNode(temp);
list.displaylist();
```

This is the LinkedList class, and the `deleteNode` function.

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    struct ListNode
    {
      T data ;
      struct ListNode * next;
    };

    ListNode *head;

public:
    LinkedList() { head = nullptr; }
     ~LinkedList();

    void insertNode(T);
    bool deleteNode(T);
    void displayList() const;
};

template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::deleteNode(T toBeDeleted)
{
    ListNode *pCur;
    ListNode *pPre;

    if (!head)
        return true;

    pCur = head;
    pPre = NULL;
    while (pCur != NULL && pCur->data < toBeDeleted)
    {
         pPre = pCur;
         pCur = pCur->next;
    }

    if (pCur != NULL && pCur->data == toBeDeleted)
    {
        if (pPre)
            pPre->next = pCur->next;
        else
            head = pCur->next;
        delete pCur;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What is `CheckAcct`? Does it have `operator<` and `operator==` defined?

Comment: @Nacho CheckAcct is a derived class from another base class and yes it does have those defined

Comment: Why didn't you just use `std::list`?  You're using `vector`, so why not use `std::list`?  Plus I can easily break your linked list with a 3 line main program that copies one list to another.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Guess he wants to learn how linked list work internally?

Comment: @Nacho Well that is done using pencil and paper, drawing lines and boxes denoting the links and how each operation is done.  That should have been done way before trying to write a program to do this.

Comment: Did you debug?  Or even print the return value of `deleteNode`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm not sure what `std::list` is. I think I'm not supposed to use it. I tested with an output statement and just found out where it stops at. `while (pCur != NULL && pCur->data < toBeDeleted)` prints out my test output statement 3 times and skips the `if (pCur != NULL && pCur->data == toBeDeleted)`. I'm not sure why its doing this.

Comment: @Mark -- The `std::list` is the C++ linked list class.  Or for your purposes, `std::forward_list` is the singly linked list class.  Second, did you do as my previous comment stated, and to draw the operation out on paper using boxes or lines, or are you trying to "program your way" to a solution?  If it's the latter, that is not how you should approach assignments like this.  Linked list assignments are to be first done on paper using lines and boxes, and then you implement what you see on paper.  It's a simple matter of deleting an item from a linked list **if** you have a visual cue.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Okay. I will try drawing everything out on paper right now.

Answer (score 1):

Your code depends on the list being sorted.  I'd guess that maybe it isn't sorted?  If that's the case, you could make your while loop and if statement:

```
while (pCur != NULL && pCur->data != toBeDeleted)
{
     pPre = pCur;
     pCur = pCur->next;
}

if (pCur != NULL)
```

I expect that will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the debugger helped out a bunch. Found out the issue was the `operator<` function didn't return correctly. One change to the return value solved everything.